# VLQ answer flag disputed, despite the answer's being in the wrong language. Why?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

I recently came across [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23555587) in the wrong language and thought "I'll save anyone else from having to see this!" I flagged it as VLQ believing it a good [fit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189373/209360):

> This content should not exist. Delete it. Now. It is not salvageable through editing.

I mean, maybe not "delete it now" like it's urgent...but definitely delete it.

---

I figure either

1. I'm wrong and the answer deserves (according to a mod or queue voters) to live on forever or
2. I should have used a custom flag saying "read the comments, where the
   author says it's garbage"

...but can't figure out which it is.

Comment: I almost never flag anything because most problems I see can be fixed with close-votes and editing. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It wouldn't be obvious to many viewers that this answer wasn't just *wrong*. It wasn't obvious to me; I don't use Perl or Ruby, so I had to look up a few things to confirm the claims made in the comments.

At which point I *did* delete the answer.

VLQ is pretty hit & miss with stuff like this; if it isn't obvious to whoever is reviewing the flag, it probably won't seem *very* low quality. I would tend to recommend you just flag as "in need of moderator intervention" and type a succinct explanation, something like *"author mistook this for a Perl question, answer is irrelevant and potentially slows down future readers"*.

Comment: Using Ruby wouldn't have helped you, that question is about R-the-statistics-computational-language

Answer (score 7):

I have a differing, or possibly a clarifying, position...  Please consider these three scenarios:

First scenario:

> Somebody asks a programming question about an algorithm and I provide an answer using pseudocode.

Second scenario:

> Somebody asks a programming question tagged [vb-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb-net) about an algorithm and I provide an answer using pseudocode

Third scenario:

> Somebody asks a programming question tagged [vb-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb-net) about an algorithm and I provide an answer using C#

Now, of the above three scenarios, which are acceptable, and which should be deleted because they are Very Low Quality (aka unsalvageable junk)?

I'd argue that all of them are acceptable.  The first scenario is obviously acceptable.  Pseudocode is always an option for describing how one would construct an algorithm.

The second scenario is also acceptable.  I might not have provided the OP a compilable solution to their problem, but I have provided them information they may use to construct one on their own.  We do not delete answers that are incomplete or that contain syntax errors.  As long as the answer attempts to help the OP with their issue, they are worth something.

Now, the third scenario... Should this be deleted?  I would argue not, as an answer in another language *is still a form of pseudocode*.  The OP would still have to read and understand the pseudocode (so, please hold your counter-examples of Brainfuck pseudocode, thanks) and then construct their solution in their guttural language of choice, but it is still equivalent to the second scenario.

I'd suggest judging the answer on the basis of whether or not the OP could use the information provided in the answer in their own language after translation, and voting appropriately.  If the example relies on elements not available in the OP's platform (e.g., javascript pseudocode + jquery to answer a VB question), then that is worthy of a downvote, comment, and if truly egregious--a delete vote.  But if that pseudocode-that-seriously-looks-like-C# answer contains what the OP needs, then toss 'em an upvote.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. In this instance, it is not an algorithm, though, just a simple helper function, for parsing a whitespace-separated string like `"word egad bah"` into a vector of strings, looking in R like `c("word","egad","bah")`. While one can imagine algorithmic concerns, like how to do this most efficiently, it's not really about that, so pseudocode doesn't really help much. (I'm not 10k and so can't review the deleted answer in light of what you say here yet, though.) By the way, you say "judging the question" in the last para, but mean "the answer", right?

Comment: @Frank ya, fixed.

Comment: Well, one can see "specific programming language" as a form of pseudo-code. Though the fake is worse than real pseudo-code, because it means you have to know that language, at least good enough to extract the algorithm. So, it depends on how close the "specific language" and the language in the question are whether it's acceptable, though one only has to assess the part of the language actually used. If in doubt, it's probably too far apart.

Comment: In your hypothetical, C# has the added benefit of basically being VB.NET code with semicolons and curly braces.